# Envío de JSON con fetch y recibida en php sin FormData

Tags: php, javascript, json

Mi siguiente inquietud es como puedo recibir un `JSON` pasado por el `body` de `fetch` de `JavaScript` en `PHP` y validar en la respuesta de texto que llegaron cada uno de sus indices con sus respectivos valores.

**Petición dirigida hacia el controlador**

```
function ensayar() {
let objeto = {
    "nombre": "Jean Carlo",
    "apellido": "Castaño Millan",
    "Telefono": 31222020
};
fetch('http://localhost:/AgroVirtual/Enrutador/ensayando', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(objeto)
})
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.text();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    })
}
```

**Controlador desde el backend procesando la petición**

```
 public function ensayando(){
    $datos = json_decode($_POST, true);
    print_r($datos);
}
```

**Resultado esperado**

```
stdClass Object ( [nombre] => Jean Carlo [apellido] => [telefono] =>               
Castaño Millan [Telefono] => 31222020  )
```

Realmente esta es la respuesta que deseo, que mi `JSON` me retorne en el `response text` que se transformo en un objeto nativo de `PHP` para poder seguir trabajando con el posteriormente desde el `backend`.

**Nota:** Esto antes lo lograba de igual forma con ***XmlHttprequest***, pero me cambie a ***fetch*** y ese es el único obstáculo que he tenido por el momento.

Comment: Te refieres a hacer un return de `json_encode($datos, true)`?

Answer (score 4):

Para empezar, cuando se envían datos por `POST`, es una buena práctica y altamente recomendable, indicar el formato en que los datos están siendo enviados.

En este caso, el formato es `application/json`, por lo que tu `JS` debería ser así:

```
function ensayar() {
  let objeto = {
    "nombre": "Jean Carlo",
    "apellido": "Castaño Millan",
    "Telefono": 31222020
  };
  fetch('result.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(objeto),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'// AQUI indicamos el formato
      }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.text();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error(error);
    })
}
```

**NOTA:** En tu `PHP`, deberías leer dicho encabezado usando [`$_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]`](https://www.php.net/reserved.variables.server) y en base al valor de esta variable, **implementar la forma para obtener los datos**.

---

Una forma para obtener los datos enviados por `POST` en formato `application/json` es leer [`php://input`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/wrappers.php.php), así:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

La variable `$json` será un `string` equivalente al enviado en el `body` de `fetch`.

Para convertir dicho `string` a un `object` puedes usar [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php), así:

```
$datos = json_decode($json, false); // Indicamos que NO deseamos una array como resultado
```

En resumen, tu controlador podría ser así:

```
public function ensayando()
{
    $datos = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    print_r($datos);
}
```

Comment: Estuve renegando buscando la forma de traer los datos y nada funcionaba, hasta que di con tu respuesta.