# recibir POST a la callback URL y responder con HTTP 200 en php cURL

Tags: curl, php8, callback

tengo el siguiente problema me estoy conectando a una la api de MercadoLibre para sincronizar mi tienda online  con MercadoLibre pero hasta este punto todo esta bien, tengo todo sincronizado, pero ellos me envían unas notificaciones cuando algún articulo cambia o si algo pasa en la pagina, y eso es lo que no entiendo como recibo yo desde mi web estas notificaciones  con php cURL y luego las tengo que responder con http 200 para ver que todo se recibió con bien. yo tengo mi  url donde deberían estar llegando las notificaciones pero lo que no tengo ni idea es como recibirlas.

les dejo por acá un poco de la documentación, yo solo necesito recibir el valor de ítem y al recibirlo ps lo demás si lo se hacer, lo que no entiendo es como recibo o pruebo que realmente me esten llegando con bien los valores que me envian.

https://developers.mercadolibre.com.ar/es_ar/productos-recibe-notificaciones

esto sale en la documentación también pero perdonen mi ignorancia, no tengo idea de como recoger ese valor, resourse ... al tener el array lo se recorrer sin problema, pero lo que no se es como obtener ese array que me tiene que llegar.

agradezco su ayuda.

```
{
   "_id":"f9f08571-1f65-4c46-9e0a-c0f43faas1557e",
   "resource": "/items/MLA686791111",
   "user_id": 123456789,
   "topic": "items",
   "application_id": 2069392825111111,
   "attempts": 1,
   "sent": "2017-10-09T13:44:33.006Z",
   "received": "2017-10-09T13:44:32.984Z"
}
```

Comment: Hola, lo entendiste mal. Si te fijas ellos te envían por POST un JSON. Vos procesas ese JSON, y si queres con esa info (_dependiendo del tipo de notificacion_) podes obtener más info, por ejemplo, haciendo un `curl` al endpoint correspondiente.

Comment: Puede que te sea de ayuda leer [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/291762/16597) (_la parte PHP_)

Comment: hola muchas gracias, si ya investigue un poco y estoy procesando los datos.